# Migrating to AngularJS 1.6 : 404 not found error on $resource call to backend server

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, migrating

We are migrating from angular 1.1 to angular 1.6.
We added the dependencies and made gulp serve.
Now when we hit localhost:3000, the UI doesnot load and complains- "server responded with 404"
From console we can see, all $resource call to backend servers is returning 404 not found error.
Whereas backend is up and running and responding well on direct call-i.e "localhost:8090/app/getinfo

config.js has proxy setting to redirect localhost:3000 to locahost:8090/app

Is there anything we are missing to add, while migrating to angular 1.6.

Thanks,

Comment: Open up the browser's developer tools, check out the network tab and see what/where the app is calling.

Comment: I checked in network tab as well. It calls localhost:3000/app/getinfo and response is "cannot GET /app/getinfo"

Comment: but call to localhost:8090/app/getinfo - responds with result.

Comment: I even noticed, the call to localhost:3000/_hash_/assets/images/pic1.jpg is also responding 404 not found.